# EpiServer: How to insert TinyMce editor into webform's control (ascx)?

Tags: knockout.js, webforms, episerver

I'm creating a plugin in the Episerver edit mode, it will be available below "Select view" dropdown button as a new label. Inside the plugin, I want to add two TinyMce editing fields, the values of which I will be able to process later. Processing them will not be an issue, but I have a big problem how to add such editing fields TinyMce to the ASCX control I created?

```
<div class="tiny-wrapper">
    <textarea type="text" class="episize500" id="EmptyReportBody" runat="server"> </textarea>
</div>
```

I passed the initiation options of TinyMce in the KnockOut Model but I still do not know how I could use them, does anyone have any idea?

```
public TinyMCEInitOptions TinyMceInitOptions
{
    get
    {
        var options = this.tinyMceInitOptions
                      ?? (this.tinyMceInitOptions =
                          TinyMCESettingsForMessagingTool.GetTinyMceInitOptions(this.CurrentPage));
        object pluginsObject;
        if (options.InitOptions.TryGetValue("plugins", out pluginsObject))
        {
            var plugins = pluginsObject.ToString();
            plugins = plugins.Replace("epiexternaltoolbar", "").Replace(",,", ",");
            options.InitOptions["plugins"] = plugins;
        }
        return options;
    }
}
```

Comment: Solved: I've created a new class that inheritances System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox in with I register startup script to the TinyMce JS file, it works.